# bootstrap dropdown as select in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I need to listen changes in bootstrap dropdown element (button)

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button 
    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
    type="button" 
    id="dropdownMenuButton" 
    data-toggle="dropdown" 
    aria-haspopup="true" 
    aria-expanded="false">
    USD
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <button class="dropdown-item">USD</a>
    <button class="dropdown-item">EUR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and transmit selected value into Vue component.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <button @click="select('USD')" class="dropdown-item">USD</a>
    <button @click="select('EUR')" class="dropdown-item">EUR</a>
</div>


select(val){
    this.val = val
}
```